# c++ Array class template with template parameters

Tags: c++, c++-templates

i have Created an Array class template with template parameters <element type, size > and
array class members, input, sort, and output functions.

but code does not work below what might i be doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T, int n>
  class array {
    T mass[n];
    public:
      void input();
    void output();
    void sort();
  };

template <class T, int n>
  void array < T, n > ::input() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cin >> mass[i];
  }

template <class T, int n>
  void array < T, n > ::output() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout << mass[i] << '\0';
  }

template <class T, int n>
  void array < T, n > ::sort()[T x; int p = 1, m = n;
    while (p) {
      p = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
        if (mas[i] > mas[i + 1])
          [x = mass[i]; mass[i] = mass[i + 1]; mass[i + 1] = x; p = 1;
          }
      m--;
    }
  }

int main() {
  array < int, 10 > a;
  array < float, 5 > b;
  a.input();
  a.sort();
  a.output();
  b.input();
  b.sort();
  b.output();
  return 0;
}
```

i get the following compiler error what might i be doing wrong in this code ?

````
   25 |   void array < T, n > ::sort()[T x; int p = 1, m = n;
      |                                  ^
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:25:33: error: expected ']' before 'x'
   25 |   void array < T, n > ::sort()[T x; int p = 1, m = n;
      |                                 ^~
      |                                 ]
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:25:52: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
   25 |   void array < T, n > ::sort()[T x; int p = 1, m = n;
      |                                                    ^
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:26:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'
   26 |     while (p) {
      |     ^~~~~
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:32:7: error: 'm' does not name a type
   32 |       m--;
      |       ^
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:33:5: error: expected declaration before '}' token
   33 |     }
      |     ^
/tmp/ZOMErK6tKN.cpp:34:3: error: expected declaration before '}' token
   34 |   }```
````

Comment: Is that a typo and you intended to put a `{` instead of `[` there?

Comment: Changing the 2 `[` to `{` and adding an `s` to the variable `mas`, because the name is `mass` will fix your problems. Voting to close because of typos.

Comment: oh my bad, it's a typo ,it works now , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos in your code. In particular, you have use `[` instead of `{` and `mas` instead of `mass`. These are correct and highlighted using comments in the below code:

```
template <class T, int n>
//----------------------------v------------------->[ changed to {
  void array < T, n > ::sort(){T x; int p = 1, m = n;
    while (p) {
      p = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
//----------vvvv------vvvv----------------------->mas changed to mass
        if (mass[i] > mass[i + 1])
//--------v-------------------------------------->[ changed to {
          {x = mass[i]; mass[i] = mass[i + 1]; mass[i + 1] = x; p = 1;
          }
      m--;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
void array < T, n > ::sort()[T x; int p = 1, m = n;
```

should that `[` be a `{`

Also i think you can implement that sort by using the std lib

```
void array < T, n > ::sort() {
    std::sort(std::begin(mass), std::end(mass));
}
```